# how to select multiple div id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css-selectors

how can i select the 3 balls in the same function call?

here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/X3SVp/2/

```
function flipper(){
    $('#ball_1, #ball_2').each.animate({
        "left": '-90',
    }, function(){
        $('#ball_1, #ball_2').animate({
            "left": '200',
        }, flipper());
    });
}

flipper();
```

Comment: look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X3SVp/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function flipper(){
    $('#ball_1, #ball_2, #ball_3').animate({left : -90}, function() {
        $(this).animate({left: 200}, flipper);
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/X3SVp/5/)

You also need to add a position to all balls, and an initial left value, otherwise it won't work as jQuery doesn't have a starting position, and elements with a static position doesn't move.

Answer (score 1):

```
you are close

$('#ball_1, #ball_2, #ball3, #ball4').animate({left : -90}, function() {
    $(this).animate({left: 200}, flipper);
});
```

, is used to have work on multiple, each is not needed in this case

Answer (score 1):

Do you want all instances of `ball_#`?  If so, you can use the "starts with" selector:

```
$("[id^='ball_']")
```

That will select all elements with an `id` attribute that starts with "ball_".